# android shape with a repeated background

Tags: android, shapes, nine-patch

I need to do a container with this background : [image]

the background has to repeat itself within this shape (rectangle with rounded top corners).

because it's for what i know impossible to perform that with a 9patch,
i've looked into shapes, but here again, it seems impossible to get what I want...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners 
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <solid 
        android:color="@color/red"/>

</shape>
```

i can't link the shape to my :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/point1sur4"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and, my shape has its 4 corners rounded ....

hope you'll help !
Thx,
Renaud

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `android:background="@drawable/point1sur4`" instead of  `android:src="@drawable/point1sur4"`

Comment: Bitmap does not have a background property